# How to create sandbox home directory with AuFS

Tags: directory, home-directory, fstab

We have two Linux computers at work, which were replaced with new hardware so we need to install the Ubuntu OS on them. However someone set them up 4 years ago and didn't document how, so I  my question is:

- How do I setup a sandboxed home directory with AuFS?

In the current fstab file there is the following entry:

```
none /home/student aufs br:/home/.student_rw:/home/student 0 0
```

But I don't really understand what this means. Can someone elaborate? The aim is a clean home directory, that restores after every reboot, but you have to be able to change something if you unmount it first as superuser.

Answer (score 5):

AuFS started as an implementation of UnionFS Union File System.

An union filesystem takes an existing filesystem and transparently overlays it on a newer filesystem.

To install aufs:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install aufs-tools
```

How to mount two directories of a same filesystem:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp/rw
mkdir /tmp/aus
mount -t aufs -o br=/tmp/rw:/home/user none /tmp/aus/
```

The first two commands created two new directories in /tmp.

The mount.aufs is the command to mount the filesystem.

The mount command, specifies it is going to union mount /tmp/rw and /home/user under /tmp/aus.

The directory /tmp/aus will have the content of both /tmp/rw and /home/user.

The options are used in mount command are:

```
-o – specifies options to be passed to the filesystem
br – specifies a branch, where each branch is separated by colon (:).
none – specifies we don’t have any device associated with it.

mkdir /tmp/rw /tmp/aufs
mount -t aufs -o br=/tmp/rw:${HOME} none /tmp/aufs
or
mount -t aufs -o br=/tmp/rw=rw:${HOME}=ro none /tmp/aufs
```

Then, you can see whole tree of your home dir through /tmp/aufs.

If you modify a file under /tmp/aufs, the one on your home directory is not affected, instead the same named file will be newly created under /tmp/rw.

And all of your modification to a file will be applied to the one under /tmp/rw.

Source: http://aufs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but it didn't really help me. First I want to mount it via fstab, not via command line because I need it after every reboot. Second I need the home directory to stay clean and a temporary folder, which "resets" after every reboot. You know what I mean?